# Why do all C++ array elements get set despite addressing just one item?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, c-strings

I have an array of structures for which I need to convert a CString into a `char` array. This conversion occurs for 1000 data points and the output is written into a new array. So my problem is: I have a for loop that iterates through the array of CStrings and converts them into a `char` array and writes that into my "new" array. The problem is that each iteration writes the newly converted `char` array to all previous array elements. E.g `newArr[0]` = `oldArr[0]` = working. `newArr[1]` = `oldArr[1]` BUT now `newArr[0]` also = `oldArr[1]`. Then `newArr[2]` = `oldArr[2]` but again `newArr[0]`, `newArr[1]` and `newArr[2]` = `oldArr[2]`.

My code is as follows:

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i < MAX_TAGS; i++)
{
    char nodeStr[40];
    strcpy_s(nodeStr, (strlen(theConf.confP[i].nodeID) + 1), theConf.confP[i].nodeID);
    monitoredNodes[i] = UA_NODEID_STRING(theConf.confP[i].namespaceIndex, nodeStr);
}
```

I guess I've done something wrong here but I've tried all sorts including looking at compiler optimisations but every time its the same problem, despite me setting an array item by index, all previous array items seem to get written too.

Comment: That's not the correct way to use strcpy_s, the 2nd parameter should be the sizeof the destination (nodeStr).

Comment: What does `UA_NODEID_STRING` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep creating and destroying `char nodeStr[40]` buffer on each loop of iteration. That buffer gets created at the same stack address where the buffer from previous iteration resided, this is why it looks like you overwrite the previous values. You probably want that buffer to persist rather than be overwritten.

You probably do not need to copy the string, just pass use its internal zero-terminated buffer:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < MAX_TAGS; ++i) {
    char const* nodeStr = theConf.confP[i].nodeID.GetBuffer();
    monitoredNodes[i] = UA_NODEID_STRING(theConf.confP[i].namespaceIndex, nodeStr);
}
```

If `UA_NODEID_STRING` creates/formats a new string, it is best for it to return a `CString` or `std::string` by value and make `monitoredNodes` an array of those, e.g. `CString monitoredNodes[MAX_TAGS];`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, that worked. I understand the char nodeStr[40] was incorrectly inside the loop but I had tried it outside too with same behaviour. It was like the array element was pointing to the converted string all of the time. Your suggestion helped me though and is now working. Thanks again!

Comment: That buffer **may** get created at the same stack address where the buffer from previous iteration resided, and there's no guarantee what happened to the data at that address in the interim. It's better to avoid such low-level claims.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If the buffer was created in a different place that for loop would eventually exhaust stack. You may like to specify the conditions when that buffer would be created in a different place. I can think of one: `alloca` inside the loop.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Nobody here's doing that though